# How to write a multi-line shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, shell-exec

I have a remote machine where I want to replace the contents of the file.

I am using the following commands

```
ssh abc@host
abc
sed -i s/enable=false/enable=true/g /config/pqr.properties
```

where abc is the username and password.

How do I put that in a shell script?

Comment: You can use `ssh ... "command1; command2"`

Comment: Use a key-pair instead.  If that's not an option you'll need to go for expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad way:

To write an `expect` script to feed password to ssh.

The right way:

To generate a key for ssh and do authorization via ssh key. Your command will look like:

```
ssh abc@host 'sed -i s/enable=false/enable=true/g /config/pqr.properties'
```

Comment: I have put this command in a file name abc and now when I am executing it its not asking for password but its not modifying the file also. Is there any way we can provide the password in the shell

Comment: Have you made a key and copied it to target server?

Comment: The Remote machine I am going to use will be dynamic so I cant put a file with key there.

Comment: So in that case you have to write an `expect` script ( or just google it ) for ssh.

Comment: I have written an expect script and its working for me. Thanks for all your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Setup authorized keys as outlined here http://wiki.qnap.com/wiki/How_To_Set_Up_Authorized_Keys

`ssh user@host command` should subsequently work within the script.